# enabling TypeFamilies makes the code not build anymore

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I have a module coded and working, however I can't manage to enter two function signatures for it, because to enter them I must enable the `TypeFamilies` extension for the module, and when I do that, it no longer builds.

For one of them I need `TypeFamilies` because it's using [persisent/esqueleto functions](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/blob/master/src/Search.hs#L118).

The proper type would be, I believe:

```
getByIds :: (PersistEntityBackend a ~ SqlBackend) =>
   EntityField a (Key a) -> [Key a] -> SqlPersistM [Entity a]
```

(ghc suggests a more generic signature)

The other one uses [hsqml](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/blob/master/src/Search.hs#L44).

ghc suggests this signature but I guess it could be simplified:

```
  prop :: forall tr b.
          (Marshal tr, Typeable b, MarshalMode tr ICanReturnTo () ~ Yes) =>
          String -> (b -> tr) -> Member (GetObjType (ObjRef b))
```

The bottom line is, that without `TypeFamilies` I cannot write those signatures. The moment I enable `TypeFamilies`, however, the code won't build, and I don't understand why. The error looks like some polymorphic functions suddenly became monomorphic.

The error output is relatively long, you can find it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22600720/typefamilies_error.txt).

I have `TypeFamilies` enabled in several other modules of the application without problems, and that enables me to write signatures using both the `SqlBackend` & `ICanReturnTo` constraints without problems.

Is there something wrong with that module that prevents it from building with `TypeFamilies`? Or should I enable yet another extension to fix it? I didn't expect just enabling that extension to break the compilation.

Comment: What's wrong with GHC's generalised type? If it works on GHC, then it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type equality constraint `~` can only be written out if you have either `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs` enabled.

However, enabling `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs` also enables [`MonoLocalBinds`.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#mono-local-binds) As the name says, it disables generalization of locally defined variables.

If `MonoLocalBinds` prevents code from compiling, you should either write out the generalized type signatures or factor out such locals into top-level definitions. Sometimes writing out the generalized types is a bit difficult; in such cases you can try querying GHCi, or you can enable `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, write unannotated top-level definitions and then look at the inferred types.

Comment: `NoMonoLocalBinds` indeed makes it build. I didn't know that one. Right now I don't understand the difference between that and `NoMonomorphismRestriction` though, they appear to be almost about the same thing.. Anyway I know where to search now thank you!

Comment: I totally forgot that there is a `NoMonoLocalBinds` flag too.

Comment: Yes but https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#mono-local-binds says " You can switch it off again with `-XNoMonoLocalBinds` but type inference becomes less predicatable if you do so. (Read the papers!)" -- therefore I'll rather annotate the local variables as you suggested.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery, you can enable `NoMonoLocalBinds` and also turn on `-fwarn-missing-local-sigs`. This will spit out type signatures for all local polymorphic bindings without signatures. You can copy and paste, then remove `NoMonoLocalBinds`. It is very often necessary in these cases to add `ScopedTypeVariables` so your local signatures can refer to type variables around them.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery `MonoLocalBinds` and `MonomorphismRestriction` both make some bindings more monomorphic, but with very different rules and reasons for when they trigger (I know what MR is about but not so much MLB). Although when both are enabled, the rules for MLB depend some on whether MR has triggered.